# Adding behaviours to polymorphic objects

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

Let's say we have the following:

```
abstract class A;

class B : public A;
class C : public A;
....

class Main;
```

---

Class Main is the class that utilises A,B and C.
And we have a following code in class Main:

```
A obj;
....
for(i = 0; i< count; ++i)
{
    obj->Abstract_Function_In_A();        
}
```

I want to change **Abstract_Function_In_A()** in **class A** to take parameters.
The problem is that, adding any new functions in the base class means 

I have to implement the new functions in all of the child classes even if some don't use them.
 Otherwise, it may not work as expected when it's called.

Does anyone know a way around it so that I can add new functions without having to define them in all of the child classes?

Comment: What do you want to happen if someone calls the new functions on instances of classes that don't implement them?

Comment: Sounds like you don't want polymorphism to me.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I don't want the classes that don't implement them to be able to access the new functions.

Comment: @CaseOfInsanity Then just add the function as virtual to the uppermost class in which you want it to be implemented. If you want to add it to more than one class derived from the same base that should not have it, add an intervening abstract class that implements the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want class A to be abstract, simply define the "default" function (implementation and interface) in class A. Classes that overwrite this function further down the inheritance tree will get their specific behavior and classes that don't get the default.

Comment: Remember that an abstract base class can have a mixture of virtual and pure virtual functions.